# Cannot fix grammar mistakes; how should I proceed?

Tags: support, editing

I wanted to fix a grammar mistake, but I need to edit at least 6 characters. Should grammar mistakes just be left alone then?

The answer I wanted to edit: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/142324/73791

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [How to correct spelling or grammar with 5 or fewer characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291716/165773)

Answer (score 7):

> Should grammar mistakes just be left alone then?

Not at all. Please, if you see any room for improvement go for it :)

However, as we can see in the [MSE post linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291716/332286) under your question (and as you witnessed when trying to edit), there is a minimum number of characters for an edit *suggestion* to be valid.

If the change you propose is shorter than 6 characters it's probably not *that* critical.

In the future, if you see other shorter-than-6-chars edits I suggest you try to see if you can improve anything else, like phrasing, word usage (some are better suited for professional environments), punctuation, line breaks and paragraphs, etc., so perhaps you can reach the minimum and submit your proposed edit.

Eventually, when you get the corresponding reputation (2k), you will be able to [edit any post regardless of its length](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).